# What is the correct way to place objects in their places on a grid using OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl

For the sake of argument, let's say I want to place a wall object (for simplicity, let's pretend it's just a 1x1 square) on a 2d grid which is 20x20.  Let's say I have the object modeled out in coordinates between 0 and 1.

So, my question is, using openGL in the correct manner (I realize there are plenty of ways I could change the coordinates manually, but that doesn't edify me for the future), how do I place this object on the grid in the location (5,5)?  Would it be related to the model matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you have the right idea.

If your wall exists in model space from (0,0) to (1,1), and you want to position a particular instance of this wall at (5,5) through (6,6), than an appropriate thing to do would be to draw this wall with a Model Matrix that is translated by 5 units in the x and y direction.

Comment: So, would I multiply the model matrix with a translation matrix, multiply that by the view and projection matrix, then pass that into the vertex shader?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the transformation matrices to place single primitives. Everytime you change a uniform (aka matrix) it's very likely the rasterizer pipline must be flushed, which is a sure performance killer.

As a general rule, to be efficient, a given transformation matrix should be applied to at least 100 primitives within a scene. So if you have some grid of tiles, it's better to either duplicate-translate them into a larger Vertex Array, or use instancing (if available).

Comment: That's good to know.  What do you mean by instancing specifically?

Comment: @xtraorange: See the reference on glDrawArraysInstanced: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArraysInstanced.xml – use the new shader variable gl_InstanceID to index into a buffer (uniform array or 1D texture) with the target positions of the geometry.